# std::distance not giving expected output

Tags: c++, for-loop, distance, reverse, stdvector

std::distance is returning the same value in a for loop, despite one of the arguments changing on each loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> q{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto i = q.rbegin(); i != q.rend(); i++) {
        static int index_dif = distance(i, q.rend());
        cout << *i << ": " << index_dif << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
5: 5
4: 5
3: 5
2: 5
1: 5
```

Despite the fact that `i` increments on each loop, so I would expect the distance between `q.rend()` and it to shrink as the loop progresses, like so:

```
5: 5
4: 4
3: 3
2: 2
1: 1
```

Instead it seems to be giving the distance between `q.rbegin()` and `q.rend()` every time.

Comment: What effect did you expect the `static` declaraton to have?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what `static` could be used for. Initially the code was inside *another* loop, so I thought `static` would save it being reinitialised every time. But I just read up a bit more, and `static` means you can perform arithmetic on a variable, but not reassignment?

Comment: `static` has nothing to do with whether you can do arithmetic or not.

Comment: Reassignment is ok: `static int index_dif;  index_dif = distance(i, q.rend());` would work.

Comment: I see, thank you, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` variables are only initialized once, so this line:

```
static int index_dif = distance(i, q.rend());
```

will only use the first value of `i` to initialize `index_dif`.

Remove the `static` and you should see the expected output.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/QJKQ5C).